# HashSet with complex equality

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following class

```
public class X
{
    //Unique per set / never null
    public ulong A { get; set; }

    //Unique per set / never null
    public string B { get; set; }

    //Combination of C and D is Unique per set / both never null
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var x = (X)obj;

        if (A == x.A || B==x.B)
            return true;

        if (C+D==x.C+x.D)
            return true;

        return false;            
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I can't think of writing a hash function in which the combination of comments over the properties above apply, just like in the Equals function, in that case is my best bet returning a 0 from the `GetHashCode` or am I missing something?

Comment: Returning zero on different states is VERY bad solution.

Comment: I can't understand how you can qualify the two objects as equal without fully verifying that `A=A`, `B=B`, `C=C`, and `D=D`...

Comment: @eocron06 what is really bad is returning changing value of `GetHashCode`... Returning 0 all the time at least satisfies contract that value should not change while item is in a container. Indeed it makes HashSet operations O(n), but at least they would produce correct results.

Comment: Why do even need to override Equals then? Just write comparer and don't use HashSet.

Comment: @eocron06 , returning the same value is bad, not just zero.

Comment: This is pretty obvious.

Comment: @pkuderov In this special case you have to return the same hashcode for every instance. The best option would be `return GetType().FullName.GetHashCode();`

Comment: Your `Equals` function is not valid as it's not transitive: `{A=0, B=1} == { A=1, B=1} == { A=1, B=0}` but `{A=0, B=1} != { A=1, B=0}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. This is fundamental problem. In fact it is possible, but it is VERY hard problem to solve.

**Explanation**

Just think about it in reverse, in which cases your objects are NOT equal? From code I can see what they are equal by this expression:

```
return A == x.A || B==x.B || (C+D)==(x.C+x.D)
```

And not equal expression:

```
return A!=x.A && B!=x.B && (C+D)!=(x.C+x.D)
```

So your hash should be same for any particular value in equality expression and same for any particular value in not equality expression. Values can vary to **infinity**.

The only real possible solution for both expressions is **constant value**. But this solution is not optional in performance cause it will just evaporate every meaning of GetHashCode override.

Consider using IEqualityComperer interface, and equality alghorithms for task you are solving.

I think best solution to find equal objects is **Indexing**. You can see for example how databases are made, and how they use bit-indexing.

**Why hashes is so cruel?**

If it were possible, all databases in the world would easily hash everything in single hash table, and all problems with fast access will be solved.
For example, imagine your object not as object with properties but as entire object state (for example 32 boolean properties can be represented as integer).

Hash function calculates hash based on this state, but in your case you explicitely tell that some states from it's space is actually equal:

```
class X
{
    bool A;
    bool B;
}
```

Your space is:

```
A      B
false  false  -> 0
false  true   -> 1
true   false  -> 2
true   true   -> 3
```

If you define equality like this:

```
bool Equal(X x) { return x.A == A || x.B == B; }
```

You basicaly define this state equality:

```
0 == 0
0 == 1
0 == 2
0 != 3

1 == 0
1 == 1
1 != 2
1 == 3

2 == 0
2 != 1
2 == 2
2 == 3

3 != 0
3 == 1
3 == 2
3 == 3
```

This sets should have same hash: {0,1,2} {0,1,3} {0,2,3} {1,2,3}

So, all your sets should be EQUAL in hash. This concludes that this is impossible to create Hash function better than constant value.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would say that the hash code that defines an object as unique (i.e. overriding `GetHashCode`) shouldn't be the one used for your specific `HashSet`.

In other words, you should consider two instances of your class equal if their properties are **all** equal (not if any of the properties match). But then, if you want to group them by a certain criteria, use a specific implementation of `IEqualityComparer<X>`.

Also, strongly consider making the class immutable.

Apart from that, the only hash code I believe will really will work is constant. Anything trying to be smarter than that will fail:

```
// if any of the properties match, consider the class equal
public class AnyPropertyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<X>
{
    public bool Equals(X x, X y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(y, null) ||
            object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return false;

        return (x.A == y.A ||
                x.B == y.B ||
                (x.C + x.D) == (y.C + y.D));                
    }

    public int GetHashCode(X x)
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Since you will have to evaluate all properties in any case, a `HashSet` will not help much in this case and you might as well use a plain `List<T>` (in which case insertion of a list of items into a "hashset" will degrade to `O(n*n)`.

Answer (score -3):

You could consider creating an anonymous type and then returning the hashcode from that:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Check that an existing code hasn't already been returned

    return new { A, B, C + D }.GetHashCode();
}
```

Make sure you create some automated tests to verify that objects with the same values return the same hashcode.

Bear in mind that once the hashcode is given out, you must continue to return that code and not a new one.